# Rails model belongs to either one model or another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For a CRM app, I want to be able to associate a Person model directly to an Account model or to a Company model which in turn is associated to an Account model.  Also, I want to associate an Address model to either a Company or a Person.  This is what I have in mind:

```
class Account
    has_many :Persons
    has_many :Companies
end

class Person
    belongs_to :Account
    belongs_to :Company
    has_one :Address
end

class Company
    belongs_to :Account
    has_many :Persons
    has_one :Address
end

class Address
    belongs_to :Person
    belongs_to :Company
end
```

So an Account would be either a "person account" or a "business account" depending on the association.  They would be mutually exclusive.  I plan to have the foreign keys account_id and company_id in the Person table.  By the same token I would have the foreign keys person_id and company_id in the Address table.  One foreign key would be null in each case.

Is this okay in Rails?  If not, any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can use model validation to make sure that only one type of association exists. Not sure what the bigger picture answer is...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at polymorphic associations. I think that's what you are looking for:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

```
class Account
     belongs_to :User, :polymorphic => true
end

class Person
     belongs_to :Account, :as => :User
     belongs_to :Company
     has_one :Address, :as => :User
end

class Company
     belongs_to :Account, :as => :User
     belongs_to :Persons
     has_one :Address, :as => :User
end

class Address
     belongs_to :User, :polymorphic => true
end
...
```

Greetings Sven

Comment: Thanks Sven!  That's exactly what I needed.  Just read about Polymorphic Associations in "The Rails 3 Way".  I appreciate your help.